# Error with purrr functions: " Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and

Tags: r

I run the following code and I get this error. I have no idea why. I've looked at other questions and could not find something similar that offered a solution that worked.

This code worked until I restarted my machine:

`:=(purrr:map_dfc(myvars, ~lag(value, .x)))`

> Error:
> Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").

```
zip <- c("48104", "02909", "49221", "39211")
dates <- c(paste0("X", seq.Date(
  as.Date("2022-01-01"), as.Date("2022-01-10"), "days"
)))
df <- data.frame(matrix(NA,4,length(dates)+1))
names(df) <- c("zips", dates)

df$zips <- zip

for(i in 2:ncol(df)){
  df[,i] <- rnorm(4,0,1)
  
}

## Convert data set from wide to long and resort by zip and date
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df_long <- df %>%
  gather(dates, value, -zips) %>%
  arrange(zips, dates)

## And then this works

lags <- seq(1:5)

# approach with one variable
myvars <- lags %>% purrr::set_names(., paste0("value_lag", .))

df_long_final <- df_long %>%
  dplyr::group_by(zips) %>%
  mutate(purrr:map_dfc(myvars,
                 ~ lag(value, .x)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try -

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

lags <- 1:5

bind_cols(df_long, 
  map_dfc(lags, ~df_long %>% 
            group_by(zips) %>% 
            transmute(!!paste0("value_lag", .x) := lag(value, .x)) %>%
            ungroup %>%
            select(-zips)))

#    zips       dates       value  value_lag1  value_lag2 value_lag3 value_lag4 value_lag5
#1  02909 X2022-01-01  1.04919201          NA          NA         NA         NA         NA
#2  02909 X2022-01-02  0.43645283  1.04919201          NA         NA         NA         NA
#3  02909 X2022-01-03  1.25871623  0.43645283  1.04919201         NA         NA         NA
#4  02909 X2022-01-04 -0.94912865  1.25871623  0.43645283  1.0491920         NA         NA
#5  02909 X2022-01-05  1.05212359 -0.94912865  1.25871623  0.4364528  1.0491920         NA
#6  02909 X2022-01-06  0.96369104  1.05212359 -0.94912865  1.2587162  0.4364528  1.0491920
#7  02909 X2022-01-07  0.50676834  0.96369104  1.05212359 -0.9491287  1.2587162  0.4364528
#8  02909 X2022-01-08 -0.14424421  0.50676834  0.96369104  1.0521236 -0.9491287  1.2587162
#9  02909 X2022-01-09 -0.02381064 -0.14424421  0.50676834  0.9636910  1.0521236 -0.9491287
#10 02909 X2022-01-10  0.10821404 -0.02381064 -0.14424421  0.5067683  0.9636910  1.0521236
#11 39211 X2022-01-01  0.15921568          NA          NA         NA         NA         NA
#12 39211 X2022-01-02  0.39791837  0.15921568          NA         NA         NA         NA
#13 39211 X2022-01-03  0.56687703  0.39791837  0.15921568         NA         NA         NA
#14 39211 X2022-01-04  0.13089154  0.56687703  0.39791837  0.1592157         NA         NA
#15 39211 X2022-01-05 -0.10364816  0.13089154  0.56687703  0.3979184  0.1592157         NA
#16 39211 X2022-01-06 -0.12961117 -0.10364816  0.13089154  0.5668770  0.3979184  0.1592157
#...
#...
```

Comment: Took me some time to get over the MASS and dplyr conflict over the select() function, but eventually I got this to work. 

Normally I can use dplyr::select to get around the conflict, but for some reason in this context it didn't work. 

This code worked though. Thank you.